# Can't get offline members in Discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have four members on my Discord server, but two of them are offline and I can't get their ID. It used to work, but now it just stopped.

This is part of my code, and I pressed the intents button on discord bot site.

```
const client = new Client({intents: [
  Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, 
  Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, 
  Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS, 
  Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS
]});

message.guild.members.cache.forEach(element => { console.log(element.user)  });
```

Comment: Did you try doing `message.guild.members.fetch()`?

Comment: Still shows two out of four users

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`message.guild.members.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) in order to get all members of a guild.
Alter your code to the following to first fetch all members and then get their users.

```
const members = (await message.guild.members.fetch()).map(m => m.user);
```

Comment: console.log(members) 
Still shows two out of four users